# spray, scala : change the timeout

Tags: scala, timeout, spray

I want to change the timeout in a spray application, but what is the simplest way to achieve this? I saw some examples on github but they are rather complicated.

thanks.

I tried this :

```
class MyServiceActor extends Actor with MyService {

sender ! SetRequestTimeout(scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(120,"second"))
sender ! spray.io.ConnectionTimeouts.SetIdleTimeout(scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(120,"second"))
// the HttpService trait defines only one abstract member, which
// connects the services environment to the enclosing actor or test
def actorRefFactory = context

// this actor only runs our route, but you could add
// other things here, like request stream processing
// or timeout handling
def receive = runRoute( myRoute )
}
```

but the timeout seems to stay at ~5 seconds.

Comment: There are several timeouts. The easiest way to change them, is to change the configuration settings. See here for a list of settings together with descriptions: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L37

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to configure the timeout using the timeout configuration value for the underlying spray can server

```
spray.can.server {
  request-timeout = 2s
}
```

Comment: hello,thanks but where should I put this piece of code?

Comment: in your application config. see https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/release/1.1/examples/spray-routing/on-spray-can/src/main/resources/application.conf#L9
for an example project

Comment: Or even better, because stand-alone, check out the template project: https://github.com/spray/spray-template